# flutter widget testing - how to execute test to "Go Back to Prevoius Screen"

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am writing widget tests in Flutter. I am not able to find any documentation to execute "Go Back to Prevoius Screen" as I do not find any method for that. Please help with some sample "test" code for the same.

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pageBack.html

Comment: Thank you for quick response. Any sample code to refer?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This test whether there is a button, but not if the route was actually popped.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704647/how-to-test-navigation-via-navigator-in-flutter

Comment: I used *tester.pumpAndSettle() * after entering into page then tried tester.goBack() and it worked. Thank you @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Glad to hear. You could answer your own question with your solution.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when I use tester.pageBack() , I get an error zero widgets with type "CupertinoNavigationBarBackButton" (this is in widget test)  `phonePage = MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQueryData(),
          child: MaterialApp(
            home: PhonePage(),
            navigatorObservers: [observer],
          ),
        );`

Comment: @TSR I face the same error. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You have to mock navigation observer.

- First create class `class MockNavigatorObserver extends Mock implements NavigatorObserver`
- Declare `final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();` in your test file.
- Put your widget inside `MaterialApp` and add property `navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],`
- Finally inside your testWidgets block {} mock like this:

  ```
  final mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
  final backIcon = find.byIcon(Icons.arrow_back_ios);
  expect(backIcon, findsOneWidget);
  await tester.tap(backIcon);
  verify(mockObserver.didPop(any, any));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();
  ```