# How to `setUp` a `WidgetTester` for Multiple Tests in Flutter

Tags: testing, flutter, dart, widget

## 1. The Problem

The `testWidgets` function is apparently only a subcase of the `test` function.

A use case I'm trying to solve right now is to pump the same widget for multiple `testWidgets`, a `setUp` for multiple `testWidgets`. However, how can I do this if it creates a new instance inside each test?

I've tried to initialize a `WidgetTester` outside the tests, in the `main()`, but `WidgetTester` has only a private constructor:

```dart
class WidgetTester 
  extends WidgetController 
    implements HitTestDispatcher, TickerProvider {
  WidgetTester._(TestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding) : super(binding) {
    if (binding is LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding)
      binding.deviceEventDispatcher = this;
}
```

I don't quite get how the Flutter team made this work, but initializing a `WidgetTester` in the same way they did inside the `testWidgets` function isn't working for me:

```dart
final TestWidgetsFlutterBinding binding 
  = TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() 
    as TestWidgetsFlutterBinding;
final WidgetTester tester = WidgetTester._(binding);
```

## 2. An Example

A simple example would be to try to break down the tests of the Flutter demo that is created with each new Flutter project from `flutter create`. In it, we could try to separate the initial setup test of the app from the tapping action test:

```dart
testWidgets('Initial setup', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

  expect(find.text('0'), findsOneWidget);
  expect(find.text('1'), findsNothing);
});

testWidgets('Increment the counter on tap', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

  await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add));
  await tester.pump();

  expect(find.text('0'), findsNothing);
  expect(find.text('1'), findsOneWidget);
});
```

The idea would be to try to move the `await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());` into a `setUp` function.

Answer (score 8):

Below is what looks like the current way to solve for this in Flutter.

To summarize:

1. Create the `group(..)` structure inside `main()`
2. Create your own private methods from inside that structure, for each group of testing you want.  For each of these private methods:

   - Pass in the `WidgetTester` instance
   - Let them be `async`
3. And then you should only have a single call to `testWidgets(..)`

   - Inside this method, is where you call the private methods you set up to distribute test logic
   - Call each of these with `await`, so they don't run concurrently

---

So far I didn't find a way for the output to indicate each "sub-test" it ran, so just using `print(...)` statements for now.

This is a demo for some QR Code logic:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_demo/app/appRoutes.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_demo/view/appHome.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_demo/view/qrScanner.dart';

class MockNavigatorObserver extends Mock implements NavigatorObserver {}

void main() {
  group('MainPage navigation tests', () {
    NavigatorObserver mockObserver;

    _loadAppHomeScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          routes: AppRoutes.getRouteMap(),
          home: AppHomeScreen(),
          navigatorObservers: [mockObserver],
        ),
      );
    }

    setUp(() {
      mockObserver = MockNavigatorObserver();
    });

    Future<Null> _verifyLayoutElements(WidgetTester tester) async {
      print('_verifyLayoutElements');
      expect(find.byIcon(Icons.scanner), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byType(FloatingActionButton), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.byType(RaisedButton), findsOneWidget);
    }

    Future<Null> _navigateToQrScannerScreen(WidgetTester tester) async {
      print('_navigateToQrScannerScreen');

      await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.scanner));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      verify(mockObserver.didPush(any, any));

      expect(find.byType(AppHomeScreen), findsNothing);
      expect(find.byType(QrScannerScreen), findsOneWidget);
    }

    testWidgets('AppHomeScreen WidgetTester', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await _loadAppHomeScreen(tester);

      await _verifyLayoutElements(tester);
      await _navigateToQrScannerScreen(tester);
    });
  });
}
```

Thanks to:
https://iiro.dev/2018/08/22/writing-widget-tests-for-navigation-events/

- Scroll to code for this file: `test/navigation_test.dart`

====

And double-thanks, because the navigation testing logic including with this example is thanks to @iiro's post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983194/2162226

Here is the `appRoutes.dart` file:

```dart
import 'package:qr_code_demo/view/appHome.dart';
import 'package:qr_code_demo/view/qrScanner.dart';  

class AppRoutes {

  static const String AppHome = 'AppHome';
  static const String QrScanner = 'QrScanner';

  static String initialRoute() {
    return AppHome;
  }
  
  static getRouteMap() {
    
    return {
      AppRoutes.AppHome: (context) => AppHomeScreen(),
      AppRoutes.QrScanner: (context) => QrScannerScreen()
    };
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `setUpAll()` function. Use it first in the main method, outside of `group` and it runs only once.

Comment: Ok, but how to obtain `tester` in `setUpAll()` ?